# Use a fragment on a view that is not attached yet

Tags: android

I have a complex case. I show a list of devices and each device can be one several types. For each device I have one model and one fragment that renders the device.

To bind my model to fragments I have a custom list adapter. This adapter looks like this:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = new FragmentContainerView(viewGroup.getContext());

            view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
                    handleAttachedItem(view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

                }
            });
        }

        if (view.isAttachedToWindow()) {
            handleAttachedItem(view);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void handleAttachedItem(View view) {
        Device device = (Device) getItem((int) view.getTag());

        Fragment fragment = getFragment(view);

        if (fragment == null || !IsCorrectFragment(device, fragment)) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (device instanceof TrainHub) {
                TrainHubFragment trainHubFragment = new TrainHubFragment();
                trainHubFragment.setDevice(device);

                transaction.replace(view.getId(), trainHubFragment);
            }

            transaction.commit();
        }

        fragment = getFragment(view);

        if (fragment instanceof DeviceFragment) {
            ((DeviceFragment) fragment).setDevice(device);
        }
    }
}
```

To set a fragment I need to use this transaction manager and the replace method. This method only works when I use the replace method and when the view is already part of the window. Otherwise it fails with an exception.

Therefore I create the view first and when the view is later attached, I can assign the fragment.

First of all it feels very strange, but I was also running into an issue lately. I was overriding the onMeasure method on a GridView to calculate the height of the GridView based on the size of its children. But because the view has no fragment attached initially I could not calculate the height of the items. So what I had to do, was to set the height to the maximum possible height to enforce layout pass with items and then calculate the height in a second pass. It took hours to find the root cause and I think it would not be needed if I could just set the fragment when the view is created.

Comment: *"I was overriding the onMeasure method on a GridView to calculate the height of the GridView based on the size of its children."* Depending on what you're doing, a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and its height set to `wrap_content` might help with this.

Comment: Thats an awesome comment. From what I see the api is great for my use case.